# executeSQL4List error

Tags: java, sql, list, datatable, hql

Im trying call an hql and fill my datatable with the records in this list.

```
executeSQL4List Error::::::::::::::::::::::: org.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to resolve path [data.REC_NO], unexpected token [data] [select data from org.wi.core.model.VW_VISIT_ASSN_HIST where data.REC_NO = 201]
```

This is the error i get.

my code for html datatable:

```
 <p:dataTable var="Detailrec" style="width:100%" paginator="true" scrollable="false" id="_dataTable2"
                                value="#{visitBean.listDetReport}" rowIndexVar="rowNum" rows="8" draggableColumns="true"
                                paginatorPosition="top" editable="false">                   

                                <p:column style="width:10%" sortBy="#{Detailrec.START_TIME}">  
                                      <f:facet name="header">
                                            <h:outputText value="OLD START TIME" /> 
                                      </f:facet>  
                                <h:outputText value="#{Detailrec.START_TIME}"/>

                                </p:column>

                                <p:column style="width:10%" sortBy="#{Detailrec.END_TIME}" exportable="false">  
                                      <f:facet name="header">
                                            <h:outputText value="OLD END TIME" /> 
                                      </f:facet>  

                                       <h:outputText value="#{Detailrec.END_TIME}" />

                                </p:column>


                                <p:column style="width:20%" sortBy="#{Detailrec.TT_NO}">  
                                      <f:facet name="header">
                                            <h:outputText value="TT NO" /> 
                                      </f:facet>  
                                      <h:outputText value="#{Detailrec.TT_NO}"/>
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column style="width:20%" sortBy="#{Detailrec.COMMENTS}">  
                                      <f:facet name="header">
                                            <h:outputText value="OLD COMMENTS" /> 
                                      </f:facet>  
                                      <h:outputText value="#{Detailrec.COMMENTS}"/>
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column style="width:20%">  
                                      <f:facet name="header">
                                            <h:outputText value="NEW COMMENTS" /> 
                                      </f:facet>  
                                      <h:outputText value="#{Detailrec.NEW_COMMENTS}"/>
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column style="width:20%">  
                                      <f:facet name="header">
                                            <h:outputText value="EDIT TIME" /> 
                                      </f:facet>  
                                      <h:outputText value="#{Detailrec.EDIT_TIME}"/>
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column style="width:20%">  
                                      <f:facet name="header">
                                            <h:outputText value="SYSTEM COMMENTS" /> 
                                      </f:facet>  
                                      <h:outputText value="#{Detailrec.SYSTEM_COMMENTS}"/>
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column style="width:20%">  
                                      <f:facet name="header">
                                            <h:outputText value="EDITED BY" /> 
                                      </f:facet>  
                                      <h:outputText value="#{Detailrec.EDITTED_BY_NAME}"/>
                                </p:column>

                                <p:column style="width:20%">  
                                      <f:facet name="header">
                                            <h:outputText value="ALIAS" /> 
                                      </f:facet>  
                                      <h:outputText value="#{Detailrec.ALIAS}"/>
                                </p:column>



                          </p:dataTable>
```

And my function in bean that fills this datatable through a commandbutton is :

```
public void ViewHistory(Integer REC_NUM)
{
    try 
    {
        REC_NO=REC_NUM;
        SQL = "select data from VW_VISIT_ASSN_HIST where data.REC_NO ="+REC_NO;
        listDetReport = glb.getEntityMgr().executeSQL4List(SQL, whereValues, VW_VISIT_ASSN_HIST.class, false);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me solve the issue here? Im really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using column name as alias in your SQL. It's like:

```
SQL = "select data from VW_VISIT_ASSN_HIST where data.REC_NO ="+REC_NO;
```

Change it to remove alias as:

```
SQL = "select data from VW_VISIT_ASSN_HIST where REC_NO ="+REC_NO;
```

Comment: OHHHH!! Thanks a bundle, buddy. My heads somewhere else and i missed this. So, obvious.